# Regex should not match if detects one or more space characters

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

My linking structure for user input:

```
++visible part of link====invisible HTML address part of link++
```

Input string:

`some text here some text here  ++stack overflow====http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask++ some text here  ++examplesite.com====http://www.examplesite.com/article?id=1++  some text here some text here some text here some text here ++shouldnotmatch.com====http://w ww.shouldnotmatch.com/++  some text here.`

My aim:

If the part between `====` and `++` includes one or more space character(s), `preg_match_all` should not match.  So my desired output is to match with first two linking attempts. But the last linking attempt should not match since `w ww` includes one space character.

My unsuccessful attempts:

1. `\+\+(.+?)====(.+?[^ ])\+\+`
2. `\+\+(.+?)====(.+?[^ {1, }])\+\+`

Can you please correct me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your first attempt you were allowing all characters before the space verification.

Does something like this work?

```
!\+\+(.+?)====([^ ]+?)\+\+!
```

If there is always something between those parenthesis then you can drop the ?

```
!\+\+(.+?)====([^ ]+)\+\+!
```

Comment: your first proposal works and I will use. I won't use 2nd one since user may forget to type smthng btw paranthesis. thank you (will accept after 6 min)

Answer (score 1):

Try this regular expression :

```
[+]{2}(.+?)[=]{4}([^\s]+?)[+]{2}
```

Comment: One minor improvement would be to replace `+?` by `*` as they both mean the same if I'm right... Am I right?

Comment: no your are not, the question mark (?) after the quantifier (+ or *) make it ungreedy (lazy) , see http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html

Comment: @Yazmat thank you. this works too. So 2 answers are very differently structured. I can not interpret Yazmat's one so asking which one should I use?

Comment: \s supports both spaces, tabulations and new lines (in case you activate the multiline). Numbers between `{}` are quantifiers (instead of repeting for example the = four time (`====`) , you just use `={4}`

Comment: if you want to learn more about the world of regular expressions, I would recommand you this link : http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html